Oracle SQL Error ORA-01756 when inserting a string pattern in Jenkins, but works in IntelliJ IDEA Database Tool
I'm trying to insert a pattern string into the PATTERN_SETTING table in Oracle using the following SQL:
INSERT INTO PATTERN_SETTING (ID, NAME, PATTERN)
VALUES (30, 'Alphanumeric and symbol', '^[a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&''()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\\[\\]^_`{|}~]+$');

When I run this SQL in IntelliJ IDEA’s DB tool, it works perfectly.
However, when I try to execute the same script via Jenkins, I get the following error:
INSERT INTO PATTERN_SETTING (ID, NAME, PATTERN)
VALUES (30, 'Alphanumeric and symbol', '^[a-zA-Z0-9!\"#$%&''()*+,\-./:
[WARN]   code :1756
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:202)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:45)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:933)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1075)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1640)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1603)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:308)
    at com.tcg.sql.patch.DbScriptsExecutor.runScript(DbScriptsExecutor.java:212)
    at com.tcg.sql.patch.DbScriptsExecutor.integrate(DbScriptsExecutor.java:168)
    at com.tcg.sql.patch.DbScriptsExecutor.patch(DbScriptsExecutor.java:121)
    at com.tcg.sql.patch.DbScriptsExecutor.execute(DbScriptsExecutor.java:72)
    at com.tcg.sql.patch.DBPatchRunner.run(DBPatchRunner.java:49)
    at com.tcg.sql.patch.Main.entry(Main.java:19)
    at com.tcg.sql.patch.Main.main(Main.java:35)

It seems like the special characters in the PATTERN column may be causing issues during script execution in Jenkins. How can I resolve this issue?
I’ve already tried escaping single quotes by doubling them (e.g., ''), but the error persists in Jenkins. Any ideas on how to handle this?

From the SQL shown in the error message it appears be choking on the semicolon within the pattern, not the quotes. How is the statement text supplied to Jenkins? Also, have you considered using character classes?

It would be best if you showed your Jenkins code. I suspect it uses ; as a statement delimiter, and that needs to be escaped when you include it in the SQL.

If nothing else helps use the chr function to get the semicolon, which is chr(59)
Rewritten insert
INSERT INTO PATTERN_SETTING (ID, NAME, PATTERN)
VALUES (30, 'Alphanumeric and symbol', '^[a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&''()*+,\-./:'||
chr(59)||
'<=>?@\\[\\]^_`{|}~]+$');

